# Zend + Doctrine: Slow PDO connection

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm getting really slow responses from a Zend website, and xdebug shows me a 20.000ms (20 seconds) delay on the class Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection. The source code of that class is the following:

```
    namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

use \PDO;

/**
 * PDO implementation of the Connection interface.
 * Used by all PDO-based drivers.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */
class PDOConnection extends PDO implements Connection
{
    public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $password = null, array $options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement', array()));
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

What could be causing the 20 seconds connection time? It's important to note that I have other websites using PDO on the same server, but only the Zend ones are having this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost to connect did the trick.